# Void pointer and attributer constructor in a vulnerable code

Tags: c, pointers, constructor, gets

I am supposed to find the vulnerability in the code and i feel its hidden either in the `__attribute__((constructor))` or the pointer .Here i can make out that it's a void pointer but i have never encountered a pointer with () (wasnt able to find out either) so what type of a pointer is this and is the `(void(*)())` in `(void(*)())&name` for type casting or something else?Also is does the attribute constructor here play any role it feels like an empty default constructor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Ignore this thing
__attribute__((constructor))
void setup(){
  setvbuf(stdout,NULL,2,0);
  setvbuf(stderr,NULL,2,0);
  setvbuf(stdin,NULL,2,0);
}

int main()
{
  printf("What's you name?\n");
  char name[100];
  fgets(name,100,stdin);
  void(*Kekpointer)() = (void(*)())&name;
  Kekpointer();
  return 0;
}
```

i tried analyzing these functions so i came to the conclusion that pointer , the fgets function or the attribute constructor but i am not able to proceed further . i also got this hint "  for challenge , your goal is to get a shell. Flag is stored on the remote server.  Read the source code carefully and try to find out the vulnerability. This is a beginner level challenge !". but it didnt guide me anywhere. I am expecting more info on the pointer expecially

Comment: I think this is a buffer overflow vulnerability, right?

Comment: Is someone actually **teaching** `setvbuf(stdout,NULL,2,0);`?!?!?  [The proper third argument for `setvbuf()` is one of `_IOFBF`, `_IOLBF`, or `_IONBF`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6p2).  Not some magic number pulled out of a rectal database such as `2`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  but if it isnt giving any error its fine ryt?

Comment: No, it's not fine.  Programming is hard enough without adding opportunities for bugs to creep in like failing to use standard values and replacing them with magic numbers.  `_IONBF` is `_IONBF`.  Full stop.  Replacing it with some value that just happens to match an internal implementation detail is wrong.  Low standards like that is a good way to get systems getting bugs no one can figure out - code that works sometimes on some systems but not on others.  "But is works" is something only an inexperienced programmer would say.  No, you just haven't observed it to fail.  **Yet**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle well i asked the challenge creater he told he has written "
//Ignore this thing" so that u ignore it

Answer (score 1):

On any modern hosted system this code is 100% safe. Memory allocated for `name` will not have executable attributes and any attempt to execute code from there will end in an exception.

You need to make this memory executable:

```
int main()
{
  char name[100];
  size_t pagesize = getpagesize();

  mprotect(name, pagesize,PROT_EXEC);

  printf("What's you name?\n");
  fgets(name,100,stdin);
  void(*Kekpointer)() = (void(*)())&name;
  Kekpointer();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Re: what type of a pointer is this and is the "(void()())" in "(void()())&name" for type casting or something else?```:

*The left-hand side:*

```
void(*Kekpointer)()
```

----> `kekpointer` is a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning `void` (returning nothing).

*The right-hand side:*

```
(void(*)())&name
```

----> the `&` is the `address-of` operator. The typecast stands for a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning `void`. So the `address-of` `name` has been type-casted to a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning `void` (returning nothing), which matches the left-hand side.

The expression type-casts the `name` buffer to a function pointer, and then initialises the left-hand side with its address.